# Javascript game, how to unload level assets and load new ones within memory limit?

Tags: javascript, memory, garbage-collection, load, limit

I am working on a javascript Canvas game with a lot of unique assets per game level but Safari keeps crashing on iPhone as soon as I load a new level even if I dispose all the textures of the previous level.

In chrome, if I force the garbage collection using the profiler right after disposing the level, I see a decrease in memory usage so I know that the textures are correctly disposed.  Else, if I don't force the garbage collection, I have to wait a long time before I see a decrease in memory usage and sometimes it even never happens.

So my guess is that Safari doesn't detect memory has been freed and it isn't available until it is garbage collected.
I tried waiting a few seconds for the garbage collector but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to re-use memory as soon as it is freed without having to wait for the garbage collector?

Thanks!

Comment: it is important how your code is structured, pattern, do not attach vars to the window obj they will never be freed. Post code here. The garbage collector alg is complicated.

Comment: I am using Flambe as the game engine and all the game code is wrapped in a closure.  

I cannot post any game code right now but I thought about reducing the memory footprint of the level in order to be able to load the second one.  

The garbage collector should have enough time to free the memory of the first level by the time the third level needs to be loaded, am I right?